# Positioning an image inside an ImageView with max height and max width set

Tags: android, imageview

I have an `ImageView` with max height and max width both set to `100`. The figure below is clearly not a square, but you can use your imagination ;)

Figure 1:

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ ImageView    ╔══════════════╗                ║
║              ║              ║                ║
║              ║ Actual image ║                ║
║              ║              ║                ║
║              ║              ║                ║
║              ║              ║                ║
║              ╚══════════════╝                ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Anyway, If I try to set a `BitMap` to the `ImageView` that does not have a ratio of 1:1, the image is positioned like pictured in Figure 1. What I want is for the picture to be placed to the left inside the `ImageView` like pictured in Figure 2 below.

Figure 2:

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║══════════════╗                               ║
║              ║                               ║
║ Actual image ║                               ║
║              ║                               ║
║              ║                               ║
║              ║                               ║
║══════════════╝                               ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

You can see my ImageView in XML below. `maxHeight`, `maxWidth` and `adjustViewBounds` are set during runtime.

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/someImage"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textName"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    />
```

This is in a `RelativeLayout` if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 19):

try this

```
<ImageView 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:src="@drawable/home_icon" 
     android:scaleType="fitStart"/>
```

It just helps for me.

Answer (score 7):

By default, the scaleType is "fitCenter" / ScaleType.FIT_CENTER like in your first sketch.

---

To align the drawable to the ***left*** of the ImageView, as shown in your second sketch:

in the xml view:

```
<ImageView 
   android:scaleType="fitStart" />
```

or in the Java class:

```
ImageView image_view = [create new ImageView or getView from xml];
image_view.setScale(ScaleType.FIT_START);
```

---

To align the drawable to the ***right*** of the ImageView

in the xml view:

```
<ImageView 
   android:scaleType="fitEnd" />
```

or in the Java class:

```
ImageView image_view = [create new ImageView or getView from xml];
image_view.setScale(ScaleType.FIT_END);
```

Comment: Exactly the good answer to center an the image inside an ImageView, need more up vote !

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just add a drawableLeft to your View.

Like this (in your layout.xml): android:drawableLeft="@drawable/yourDrawableId"
-or-
like this (in Java code): yourView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(yourDrawableId,0, 0,0);

You can control the padding, etc of this drawable inside your View container (to control close grained layout tweaks).

Comment: And where exactly does that work? Auto-completion doesn't show me "drawableLeft".
Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and this is how I solved it:

I ended up putting the ImageView inside a RelativeLayout that is just as big as the ImageView and set the gravity of the Relative Layout to what I wanted (left in your case).

I also set adjustViewBounds to true so the ImageView is just as big as the Image and is positioned inside the Relative Layout.

Not a very elegant solution but it works...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
android:gravity="left"
```

Gravity is how a view positions its contents.  Works on TextView for text and probably ImageView for image.

Edit:

Try making a FrameLayout that contains the ImageView.  Set the ImageView width and height to "wrap_content" and set the gravity of the parent to "left".

Otherwise, implement onDraw in a View and draw the image at whatever position you want.

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).  Good luck!

**EDIT:** My bad, I didn't realize you were centering an image in an ImageView (my first reading I thought you were having trouble centering the ImageView within another View).  Now I'm not so sure, but you could look at ScaleType anyways ^_-

Answer (score 1):

Something is not right. Your ImageView is defined with `wrap_content` for both its `layout_width` and `layout_height` in the XML, so it should always only occupy the same space as your bitmap.

Try adding a `android:background` for your ImageView to see that it really is wider than your bitmap and caused the unwanted centering:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/someImage"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textName"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:background="#F00"
    />
```

Test it with some bitmaps that has transparent background color so we can see the red background from the ImageView. I expect it to show a tall rectangle if your source bitmap is tall and a wide rectangle if the bitmap is wide. You will only see a square if your source bitmap is square. We should never see the Figure 1 case from your question.

Maybe you wanted to have your ImageView to always have a 100x100 dimension at all times instead? Then you can use the following code (notice the `fitStart` for the `scaleType` attribute as correctly mentioned by others already):

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/someImage"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textName"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:background="#F00"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    />
```

There is no need to set `maxHeight`, `maxWidth` and `adjustViewBounds` from the Java code if this is what you want.